# How to I append elements to a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I've a list of lists like:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

To each of the lists I want to add an element like `0` at the beginning, so that the result looks like:

```
b = [[0,1,2], [0,3,4]]
```

What's the Python way to do it? I already tried it with "map", but without success.
I know, I could easily do it with a loop, but what's the functional way?

Comment: Minor thing, but that's not appending, it's **pre**pending or inserting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use list comprehension and addition of lists to get in done in one short line of code:

```
b = [[0]+item for item in a]
```